# Copy two variables between quotes in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently attempting of categorizing two different variables and their values from a text file:

```
text {
variable1 = "value1"
variable2 = "value2"
}
```

I was thinking of reading out the text file, line per line, looking for the variables and their values, I'm only able to read the lines I want, but I'm unable to segregate the value's:

```
with open("text,txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        if "variable" in line:
            print line
```

TL;DR, I want to be able to be able to invoke both variable's and both value's independently.

Can anyone offer some assistance in this matter?

Comment: I am not sure what asking. Do you just want to know how to pull values from a string in python?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Looking at the syntax, I am not sure whether you are using python or any other language.

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully this will give you a better picture of what I need help with

Comment: So to clarify, you are writing a program that will get the names of two variables and then open a text file and search for those variables, if it finds them it prints the line they are on. Is that about what you want to do? I am not sure what you mean by invoke.

Comment: I'm trying to read variable1, value1, variable2 and value2 from say a settings file so that I can use them for another program.

Comment: What format is the file in (it has similarities to YAML)?  If it is a formal format then there might already be a module out there that handles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site would probably give you some good examples:
[python line splitting](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-python)

You have some syntax errors and if I understand what you want it should be like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as search:
    for line in search:
        if "variable1" in line:
            print variable1, "equals", line.split('=')[1]
        elif "variable2" in line:
            print variable2, "equals", line.split('=')[1]
```

Or if you just want the variable value, change the print statement to

```
val2 = line.split('=')[1]
```

Then you can use val2 later

If there are spaces in between the equals you will need to do a strip like so:

```
val2 = val2.strip()
```

Then you can do:

```
val2 = val2.strip()
val2 = val2.split('=')[1]
```